# Changing value of array

Tags: java

I am having trouble inspecting some of my Java code.

I have an array:

```
String[][] myString = new String[3][3];
```

I then have a method:

```
public String getString(int x, int y) {

    return myString[x][y];

}
```

If I then do:

```
String tmp = getString[0][1];
tmp = "Hello";
```

Will this change the value 0,1 of myString to "Hello" or will it re-point tmp to a string reading "Hello"?

Comment: You've written almost all the code that's needed to check it ;)

Comment: Experiment with it. Run the code, then check that location in the array and see if it is the same or has changed.

Comment: @digitaljoel first OP must have to change the code in order to compile. `getString[0][1]` is not the array, instead a wrong way to call the `getString(int, int)` method.

Comment: yeah, that's why it's an experiment...

Answer (score 3):

No it won't.

Setting a new value to the variable `tmp` will no affect your array. If you want to change the value of the array you will have to do

```
myString[0][1] = "Hello";
```

Or (better) use a setter.

Comment: @fge - Why not? I don't have much experience with OOP, but I think it is considered good practice to make all variables in a class private and getters/setters for those who have to be exposed outside the class.

Comment: @user1876047 - You already have a getter in your code. It is a method that exposes values from a variable. A setter could be `public void setString(int x, int y, String val) { myString[x][y] = val; }`

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread... I though getString was an array, but it's a method

Answer (score 2):

In java, variable names are references to locations in memory. Thus:

```
String tmp = getString(0,1); 
tmp = "Hello";
```

Is equivalent to:

```
String tmp;//Declares a reference with the name 'tmp'
tmp = getString(0,1); //points 'tmp' to the result from your getter function
tmp = "Hello";//re-points 'tmp' to the string 'Hello'
```

This will not affect your original string multidimensional array `myString`.

Please note that in Java it's probably a better idea to utilize more sophisticated concepts of `Lists` rather than using raw arrays. A `List<List<String>>` will be equivalent to `String[][]` but with more functionality and portability.

Answer (score 1):

It will re-point to a `String` reading "Hello". The reassignment of hardcoded string will assign the new instance you have just created.

Comment: @fge: Thanks for clearing up the misconception I had in terminology.

Answer (score 0):

use this to change the value of array

```
myString[0][1] = "Hello";
```

And to change the value of a reference use this

```
String tmp = getString[0][1]; //points 'tmp' to a place in your array
tmp = "Hello";//now points 'tmp' to "hello" and this will not effect the array
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, as well as in many other popular languages, the left side of the "=" sign is the one that you assign value to. The right side is the assigned value.

```
VARIABLE = value_to_be_assigned_to_variable
```